# python 3 don't accept openning files with name

Tags: python

please see this photo and tell me why i can't open file with name in python and i can just open it with full addresses?

```
file = input("enter your file name: ")
fhand = open(file)
print(fhand)
```

```
Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/kernel/Documents/python/file upper.py", line 3, in <module>
fhand = open(fname)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'test.txt
```

[image: see image here]

Comment: looks like you are trying to run it from vs code your vs terminal location is home and not  Documents/python/, you might want to `cd Document/python` and then run it.

Comment: obviously, because `test.txt` is *not in your working directy*, this the relative path will not be found. Why are you showing us pictures of a terminal, but you are running your code from VS code? Did you try to check what the actual working directory was?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably your working directory is not `"/home/kernel/Documents/python/"`.

Try with `os.path` module:

```
import os

print(os.getcwd())  # To debug, display the current working directory

file = input("enter your file name: ")
fhand = open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), file))
print(fhand)
```